# How to add multiple types of objects in a class

Tags: python, django, web

Here, is the problem when I try to add multiple objects to context through get function it is not showing pagination and when views.py is like below code then I am unable to add multiple objects of different models.
Ex: I want to add two models like Items and Ads to my Homepage class then how can I do this.
Views.py

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Item
    paginate_by = 12
    template_name = "home.html"
```

home.html

```
<div class="card-body text-center">
                <a href="" class="grey-text">
                  <h5>{{ item.get_category_display }}</h5>
                </a>
                <h5>
                  <strong>
                    <a href="{{ item.get_absolute_url }}" class="dark-grey-text">{{ item.title }}
                      <span class="badge badge-pill {{ item.get_label_display }}-color">{{item.tag}}</span>
                    </a>
                  </strong>
                </h5>

                <h4 class="font-weight-bold black-text">
                  <strong>
                  {% if item.discount_price %}
                  <del>Rs. {{ item.price }}</del><br>
                  Rs. {{ item.discount_price }}
                  <span class="badge badge-pill danger-color">{{item.dis_per}}% off</span>
                  {% else %}
                  {{ item.price }}
                  {% endif %}
                  </strong>
                </h4>

              </div>
```

Comment: how are you trying to add, please show us the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the get_context_data.

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Item
    paginate_by = 12
    template_name = "home.html"
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # Call the base implementation
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['ads'] = Ads.objects.filter(
            some_condition='relevant ad')
        return context
```

You can check it in the documentation, search for "Adding extra context"

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/